# Open a div when typing the first letter in a search field as long as it is not an asterisk (*)?

Tags: javascript

I have this code below that hides the div when writing, I want the opposite; that is, do I need the div to be hidden and to appear when writing the first letter in the search field as long as it is not an asterisk (if it is an asterisk it does not open the div)?

See example at: https://jsfiddle.net/ka81e4qb/

```js
$('#search').keypress(function() {
    $('#hello').hide();
    $(this).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" autocomplete="off"/>
<div id="hello" >Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: and what have you tried ? Seems pretty straightforward. instead of hiding it, show it (hide() becomes show()), and hide it by default through CSS. Then handling the asterisk is another question, but there again you should try first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended is `$.keyup()` method as it will provide latest character too.

```
$('#search').keyup(function(event) {
    $('#hello').show();    
    if(!event.target.value.trim() || event.originalEvent.charCode === 42 || event.target.value.startsWith("*")) {
      $('#hello').hide();
    } else {
      $('#hello').show();
    }
});
```

First condition will always check whether asterisk (*) is typed & hide the div.

Comment: You can accept my answer if it has worked for you :)

Comment: Attention, after all it still doesn't work, because when writing more letters after the asterisk the div appears. The div cannot appear when the first letter is an asterisk followed by more letters.

Comment: Edited my answer, now it'll satisfy both conditions.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, now when writing without the asterisk the div never appears. https://jsfiddle.net/2srd0fpt/1/

Comment: Added default show statement and change it accordingly

Comment: Ok now it works perfectly and in full, I just have to thank you a lot because you were a tireless friend.

Comment: One thing is still missing, after deleting one or more letters the div no longer disappears, that is, when the field is empty the div does not disappear. I would be grateful if you changed the code so that when you delete all the letters in the field the div disappears too.

Answer (score 0):

**Okay, thanks for the suggestion. So to solve the first part of the problem it works with the codes below, joining the css to hide the div initially. Then the second part of the problem remains, which is never to open the div if the first letter is an asterisk (*)?**

```js
$('#search').keypress(function() {
    $('#hello').show();
    $(this).focus();
});
```

```css
#hello {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" autocomplete="off"/>
<div id="hello" >Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now we solve the 2nd part of the problem, just change the js code, which corresponds to Vaibhav suggestion. But that's not all yet ... it still doesn't work well, because when writing more letters after the asterisk the div appears. The div cannot appear when the first letter is an asterisk followed by more letters.

```js
$('#search').keypress(function(event) {
    $('#hello').show();
    if(event.originalEvent.charCode === 42) {
      $('#hello').hide();
    }
    $(this).focus();
});
```

```css
#hello {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" autocomplete="off"/>
<div id="hello" >Hello World!</div>
```